# Powershell copy mailbox permissions

Tags: powershell, office365

We are using Office365 and often when we need to create a new user it has to be an exact copy of another employee. Often these users have access to different shared mailboxes and I want to create a powershell script that copies the permissions on a sharedmailbox from a specific user to the new user so that they both have access to the same shared mailboxes.

I was able to get the permissions from one user with the following command:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User t.test@company.com
```

And I am then able to use this output to set the permission using:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity example@company.com -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping:$true -User t.test@company.com
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity example@company.com -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$false -Trustee t.test@company.com
```

But it would be great if I could do this with 1 script. So I tried the following:

```
$FUser = Read-Host "Enter the mail adress of the user you want to copy mailbox permissions from"
$TUser = Read-Host "Enter the mail adress of the user you want to set mailbox permissions for"

$GPerm = Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User $FUser

$GPerm | ForEach-Object { $_ 
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_ -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping:$true -User $TUser
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $_ -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$false -Trustee $TUser
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxAcePresentationObject" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter". Error: "Cannot convert hashtable to an 
object of the following type: Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter. Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or a Data section."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxPermission], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-MailboxPermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: Use `-Identity $_.Identity` for both `Add-` cmdlets.

Comment: hello, from a help file I see **The Identity parameter specifies the mailbox where you want to assign permissions to the user. You can use any value that uniquely identifies the mailbox.**
You are passing **$GPerm** which is not a mailbox names but rules.
Follow the @robdy advice. that should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_` represents currently processed object in `ForEach-Object`. When you run `$_` inside that command you'll see something like this:

```
Identity             User                 AccessRights                 IsInherited Deny 
--------             ----                 ------------                 ----------- ---- 
FirstName LastName   another.user@aa.com {FullAccess, ReadPermission}  False       False
```

As you can see in [`Add-MailboxPermission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps) docs (same applies to `Add-RecipientPermission` but I'll let you to find it and check yourself):

> -Identity
>
> The Identity parameter specifies the mailbox where you want to assign
>   permissions to the user. You can use any value that uniquely
>   identifies the mailbox.
>
> For example:
>
> Name
>
> Display name
>
> Alias
>
> Distinguished name (DN)
>
> Canonical DN
>
> domain name\account name
>
> Email address
>
> GUID
>
> LegacyExchangeDN
>
> SamAccountName
>
> User ID or user principal name (UPN)

Therefore you can see that you need to specify any of unique identifiers. You can use `$_.Identity` to provide the mailbox identity.

**Hint**: in this particular scenario probably it'd be useful for you to assign permissions via group as it's far easier to manage than copying the permission from one user to another.

---

Just to note - what I explained above is pretty much basic of PowerShell. I'd suggest to see some online courses to improve your PowerShell skills. Example of when you can start is [PowerShell: Beginner on MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/learning-path/powershell-beginner-12).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation using $_.Identity worked. I always thought that using groups in exchange online wasn't available but I guess after a quick search on google I see that it could work. I will check that aswell. Thanks for your help!